# Assigning a value to a global variable inside an ajax call and using it in a separate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two separate .js files and I want to assign the value of a global variable called `citId` inside an ajax call in my first .js file and then use that variable in my second .js file.

The code is too long to post, so I've put an example of what I'm trying to do.

My first .js file is `main.js`:

```
var citId = "";
$(document).ready(function($) {
var url = some url;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
                  //Does some stuff

                   urlId = product of some stuff;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + urlId,
            jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {

                if (json.length > 0) {
                    citId = urlId;
                    window.open('Citations.html', '_self');
                } else {
                var page = linkBase + urlId;
                window.open(page);
                }  
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }   
         });  

    });   
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
});
```

and my second .js file is `citations.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    var itemLnkId = citId;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + citId,
        jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json)
        // more stuff

    });
});
```

I've read a lot of answers that either show how to assign the global variable inside the ajax call or how to use a global variable across .js files but nothing that shows how to do both combined.

When I've simply used a global variable, it works for the original value but does not show the value being changed inside the ajax call. Is there some way to do both assigning a value and then using it in a different .js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a global variable why don't you pass the variable that you need using invokedata of the ajax call?

to use it in the success call.

Example http://weboutofthebox.com/en-GB/28/Article/Ajaxinvokedataparameter

Comment: I kind of understand what's happening in that example except I'm unsure how I would then use the value in my other .js file? Would I simply call the function in the other file?

Comment: in the success you can affect an global variable, but that variable will only be available when ajax ends.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not 'hold' when the AJAX call is executed, it is asynchroneous and for the second ajax call, the variable is not set yet. So... Try this:

citations.js:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
var url = some url;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
                  //Does some stuff

                   urlId = product of some stuff;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + urlId,
            jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {

                if (json.length > 0) {
                    readyToGo(citId);
                    window.open('Citations.html', '_self');
                } else {
                var page = linkBase + urlId;
                window.open(page);
                }  
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }   
         });  

    });   
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
});
```

main.js:

```
var readyToGo = function() {

    var itemLnkId = arguments[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + citId,
        jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json)
        // more stuff

    });
}
```

Something like this will do :)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code. So I still want var citId as a global variable and then would I still assign urlId to citId before I do readyToGo(citId)?? citId still needs to get the value inside the if statement? Also where is arguments[0] coming from? Just want to make sure I understand and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.actived').click(function(){         
            var status = "Actived";
            var register_id=1;
            (function(status){              
                $.ajax({                
                    //url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/home/toggleActive",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {                     
                        "register_id" : register_id,
                        "status":status
                    },
                    //datatype: 'json',
                    success: function(data){

                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });         
            })(status);

        });


I hope that it will help you...
```